# Is there a way to keep Laravel route caching automated?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-artisan

My Laravel project would auto-cache whenever I added routes.

However, my other Laravel projects do not auto-cache, I have to manually cache the routes using `php artisan route:cache`.

Comment: laravel by default doesn't have auto-caching. Are you sure that in the first project you don't have somewhere called `route:cache` or `optimize`?

Comment: Why not just make a cronjob for this?

Comment: you only need to cache the routes when you deploy and you would have the cache command part of your deployment process ... locally there is no reason to cache your routes, just keep them uncached otherwise you will have to constantly recache them after any changes

Answer (score 0):

Use cron job on production if u need to do it on specific period of time:

Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands) on setting it up in laravel project (it's pretty straightforward)

Then on server u add a cron job like this:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me also when I did
`php artisan optimize`
I had to run optimize command whenever I added a New route.

if you want PHP to solve you problem run.

`php artisan route:clear`

solved my problem.